# How do I get rid of the expected 'int(*)(const struct dirent *)' but argument is of type 'int (*)(struct dirent *)' error?

Tags: c, struct

I don't understand why my C compiler is throwing a dirent error. I initialized everything, or at least I thought I did, in according to the [man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scandir.html). And yet I am still getting thrown a dirent error. It keeps saying `expected int (*)(const struct dirent *) but argument is of type 'int (*)(struct dirent *)'`

My code:

```
extern int alphasort();

int count, i;
struct direct **files;

if(!(getcwd(pathname, sizeof(pathname))))
{
    die("Error getting pathname\n");
}
printf("Current Working Directory = %s\n", pathname);
count = scandir(pathname, &files, file_select, alphasort);

if (count < 0)
{
    die("No files in this directory.\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Number of files = %d\n", count);
    for (i = 1; i < count+1; i++)
    {
        printf("%s  ",files[i-1]->d_name);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 1;
}

pathname = char pathname[MAXPATHLEN];
```

file_select =

```
int file_select(struct direct *entry)
{
    if ((strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0) || (strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0))
        return (FALSE);
     else
         return (TRUE);
}
```

Comment: I am tried using what is directly on the manpage as well, and I am getting the same issue.

Comment: I'm not sure that error could be much more explicit. The compiler is telling you it expects a function pointer who's return type is `int` and take a sole argument of `const struct dirent *`; your `file_select` returns `int`, but its sole argument is clearly `struct dirent *` (not const). (actually, its `struct direct *`, but I assume `direct` is a typo and you didn't bother pasting your *real* code.).

Comment: Ah, yeah, as I commented on the other guys answer, the compiler threw that it was about 300 lines below that, so I thought it had something to do with that. I am also a bit tired, that could explain that. And I didn't post my real code because its very, very, very long.

Comment: Well, if you look at the guidelines, they say that you're supposed to *first* extract a minimal example to post here, shame on you! See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

You need to change your callback function so its argument matches what is expected:

```
int file_select(const struct direct *entry)
{
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! this helps a lot! I can't believe I missed it, my compiler was throwing that it was about 300 lines below, which is what I missed (its also late, time to put on more of that caffeine)

Comment: @ProgramStudent12309123 to be fair it did say exactly this in the error message